# Rank of a general matrix

Tags: matrices

Given some scalars $a_1,a_2,...,a_m \in F$ not all zero and $b_1,b_2,...,b_n \in F$ not all zero, what is the rank of the matrix $M=(a_i b_j)_{\begin{matrix}1 \leq i \leq m \\ 1\leq j \leq n \end{matrix}}$? I thought of the rank-nullity theorem, however I don't see how one can possibly determine $\mathrm{nul}(A)$ without knowing the scalars. The only thing I know for sure here is that $\mathrm{rk}(A) \leq \min(m,n)$. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The matrix $M=AB$ for particular matrices $A,B$. Do you know anything about the rank of a product?

Comment: How about independently of columns or rows?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - thanks, I forgot about it. The rank must be equal to 1 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the key is to note that the matrix can be written as a product of rank-$1$ matrices:
$$
M = \pmatrix{a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_m} \pmatrix{b_1 & \cdots & b_n}
$$

Comment: Actually, it means that $\mathrm{rank} M \leq 1$. Because $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}\ A, \operatorname{rank}\ B)$. So there is a possibility that $\operatorname{rank}(M)=0$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That is, we could have $M=0$.